# Scale UITextView with pan gesture

Tags: swift, rotation, uitextview, scale, cgaffinetransform

I'm making a feature where user can add text sticker, scale and rotate it using pan gesture by dragging on right bottom corner.

I made a custom class inherited from UIView, I put UITextView on it, 3 views on corners for buttons(close, edit and zoom/rotate) and transparent UIView on top for gestures.

Sorry, I have no enough reputation to add images

Text Sticker view structure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM4Ev.jpg

My attempt is to use CGAffineTransform on pan gesture. Pan gesture is lying on Rotate Button View (bottom left corner)

```
@IBAction func resizeGestureRecognizer(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchLocation = sender.location(in: self.superview)
        let center = self.center

        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            self.deltaAngle = CGFloat(atan2f(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))) - CGAffineTransformGetAngle(self.transform)
            self.initialDistance = CGPointGetDistance(point1: center, point2: touchLocation)
            //self.initialBounds = self.bounds
        case .changed:
            let angle = atan2f(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))
            let angleDiff = Float(self.deltaAngle) - angle
            let scale = CGPointGetDistance(point1: center, point2: touchLocation) / self.initialDistance

            // downscale buttons to ramain same size and rotation
            for button in buttonViews {
                var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
                t = t.rotated(by: CGFloat(angleDiff))
                t = t.scaledBy(x: 1/scale, y: 1/scale)
                button.transform = t
            }

            var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
            t = t.rotated(by: CGFloat(-angleDiff))
            t = t.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
            self.transform = t

//            textView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
//            textView.layer.rasterizationScale = 20
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            print("ended")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

This code works but every time I'm trying to resize or rotate sticker it scale back to original scale. What am I missing?

Result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNM8s.jpg

Also, as a workaround for scaled font quality, I'm using huge fornt size(100) and scale of 0.5 for sticker:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
        frameView.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        showEditingHandlers = true
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()

        let scale: CGFloat = 0.5

        for button in buttonViews {
            var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
            t = t.scaledBy(x: 1/scale, y: 1/scale)
            button.transform = t
        }


        var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
        t = t.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
        self.transform = t

        textView.delegate = self
        update()
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, in case someone else will be searching for similar problem, I'll post my solution

I added variables fro scale in top of my class:

```
var scale: CGFloat = 0
var savedScale: CGFloat = 0.5 // 0.5 becuase I use double font size and scaled my sticker by 0.5 to handle font blur
```

next, in my gesture handle func I just save last scale like this:

```
@IBAction func resizeGestureRecognizer(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchLocation = sender.location(in: self.superview)
        let center = self.center



        switch sender.state {
        case .began:

            print("saved scale = \(savedScale)")
            self.deltaAngle = CGFloat(atan2f(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))) - CGAffineTransformGetAngle(self.transform)
            self.initialDistance = CGPointGetDistance(point1: center, point2: touchLocation)
        case .changed:
            let angle = atan2f(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))
            let angleDiff = Float(self.deltaAngle) - angle
            scale = CGPointGetDistance(point1: center, point2: touchLocation) / self.initialDistance

            print("scale: \(scale)")
            scale = scale * savedScale // <- added this

            // downscale buttons to ramain same size and rotation
            for button in buttonViews {
                var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
                //t = t.rotated(by: CGFloat(angleDiff))
                t = t.scaledBy(x: 1/scale, y: 1/scale)
                button.transform = t
            }

            var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
            t = t.rotated(by: CGFloat(-angleDiff))
            t = t.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
            self.transform = t
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            print("ended")
            savedScale = 1 * scale // <- and this
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works perfectly. 
I struggled with this problem for a few days, but I solved it with the above codes.
thanks for leaving the solution :)